# Image not displayed in the ImageView - Intel x86 Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, imageview, android-imageview, android-image

I am trying to displaying images in imageview. I know that it can be done by passing the image path in `setImageBitmap()`.

I did it already. Because of some internal issues, my emulator performance was degraded and so I changed my emulator from **Google** to **Intel x86**. From that point, my applications, which are related to images are not working properly. Is there any issue, regarding displaying images in imageview?

Code snippet for image display:

```
try
                {
                         path = info.getPath(); //this variable contains the filename of the image.
                         File sdCardPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); // code to get the path of the folder storing the image file
                         Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(sdCardPath+"/DCIM/Camera/SAMPLE IMAGES/"+path);
                         jpgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This is reg pic : "+sdCardPath+"/DCIM/Camera/SAMPLE IMAGES/"+path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
                catch(NullPointerException er) 
               {
                        String ht=er.toString();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ht, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

The image files are stored as follows -

[image]

Comment: post some code or logcat if you got error

Comment: No @MetalHead, I did not get any error in the logcat. I even could get the path of that image in  the Toast.

Answer (score 0):

Since you changed your Emulator from Google to Intel x86  the image paths will change

you should see an error in you log cat  like this

`E/BitmapFactory(1961): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/abc.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

Try updating the image paths from your application by selecting the images again

Comment: yes, now am getting that error, what should I do for that? But I have checked the image path, that did not change.

Comment: @nki You should once again get the image path from your app the earlier stored imagepath wont work now

Comment: @nki your Sd card image has changed hence the images wont be present at the same location and Also check if the images are there in the gallery becoz sometime the all media/image files get deleted once you change the system image

Comment: They are present in the same location @MetalHead1247, please see the updated code and the image I have posted there to get a better idea. Thank you.

Comment: I can see those images in gallery also.

Comment: @nki even i was getting the same problem i solved it by getting the image path again and the setting it it worked

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37574/discussion-between-nki-and-metalhead1247)